# Android - Update ListView items without call NotifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, listview, bluetooth, listener, adapter

I am trying to develop a bluetooth API which have a listener to find all nearby bluetooth device after make it a Scan. I use this listener to store all found device in a list (every time that I find one device is stored at list)

My idea is: The developer can reference this list into his adapter to show all the nearby available devices. How I can do it to  update and notify the changes to the adapter without call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`? The reason is simply: While the device is scanning I want to display the device founded.

If you thought my idea is wrong any idea will be appreciate too.

Thanks.

Comment: Recyclerview is very useful in situations like this. you can use adapter.notifyItemInserted() it will update adapter data and also animate data entry.

Answer (score 0):

> My idea is: The developer can reference this list into his adapter to
>   show all the nearby available devices. How I can do it to update and
>   notify the changes to the adapter without call
>   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()? The reason is simply: While the device
>   is scanning I want to display the device founded.

Simply use a runnable to update any changes base on minute. This is an alternative way without calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

This code runs every minute.

```
refresh = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Clear the list
                //Call the list ie. Asynctask
                handler.postDelayed(this, 60 * 1000);
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(refresh, 60 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about how to notify about a single new data being pushed inside your list?

If so, there is an article of mine which describes process of doing this in a really detailed way [RecyclerView Adapters](http://The%20most%20elegant%20and%20frankly%20adequate%20solution%20would%20be%20not%20to%20do%20anything%20inside%20adapter!%20I%20wrote%20an%20article%20about%20adapters,%20have%20a%20look%20RecyclerView%20Adapters)